# How to block ping from my VMs with iptables?

Tags: iptables, kvm-virtualization

I have a server with 4 `KVM` VMs running on it. These VMs have only one interface and all the interfaces are connected to the same `OVS` bridge.

I was trying to block the ping on those VMs using the following iptables command

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o ${tap_interface} -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
```

However, it was not working. Then I said, let's go to the basics and block all the ping messages, even the ones from the server. So I executed:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
```

The situation now is that my server cannot ping (and I see packets hitting the previous rule) but my VMs are still able to ping. I don't understand why the traffic from the VMs is bypassing the rule.

Comment: you need to add the same for input too. iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j REJECT

Comment: It did not work for me either

Comment: `interfaces are connected to the same OVS bridge` - that's your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When routing use the FORWARD table:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
```

Comment: Ok, but in the nat tables I cannot use DROP or REJECT as an action, so how would you block those ping packets?

Comment: Don't use DROP, simply do not MASQUERADE!
`iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat ! -p icmp -j MASQUERADE`

Comment: ok, but that does not really drop the packet right? It just makes sure that the packet will never arrive to its destination. So you are telling me that it is not possible to DROP / REJECT the packet unless specified in the iptables of the node which is the source of the ping, right?

Comment: DROP means: if received this kind of packet then DROP to /dev/null.
if the packet is not MASQUERADEd, then the packet will be dropped to /dev/null. What's the difference?

Comment: AFAIK, if the packet is not MASQUERADE then it will be drop in the network because it will have a source IP which is unknown (e.g. a private source IP) but I don't think it goes to /dev/null. If I ping 8.8.8.8 from a private IP of the VM (let's say 192.168.0.2) and I don't masquerade then I see:

16:14:55.824893 IP 192.168.0.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 10300, seq 1, length 64
16:14:56.831380 IP 192.168.0.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id

Comment: that is the -t filter FORWARD chain. You may can use it for adding rules.

Comment: Yes, that works!! That was it :) Thanks. Can you update your first answer so that I can say it is correct?